# EntityFramework and custom classes with object arrays (one-to-many)

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have an external XML feed that I have generated a class from using xsd.exe.

I am trying to utilize entity framework in a web application to save the feed to a database, code-first and have been following [Using Web API 2 with Entity Framework 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/ng%20navigation%20property%20to) tutorial.

When i use **context.products.AddOrUpdate(x => x.Product_ID, products);** only a table named *products* is being created in the database with the right data, with no other table called distributor or country_markets and no relations created.

> How do make this class save to multiple tables with one-to-many
>   relationships?

#### Model Class

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace project.Models    
{
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    public class Product
    {
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        [Key]
        public int product_id { get; set; }

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Country_Markets", typeof(Country_Markets), Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Distributors", typeof(Distributors), Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public object[] items { get; set; }
    }

    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    public class Distributors
    {
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Distributor", Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public Distributor[] Distributor { get; set; }
    }

    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    public class Distributor
    {
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public string name { get; set; }
    }

    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    public class Country_Markets
    {
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Country_Market", Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public Country_Market[] Country_Market { get; set; }
    }

    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    public class Country_Market
    {
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public string shortcode { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"only a table named *products* is being created in the database with the right data"

Check in your context class whether you have DBSet properties for *distributors* and *country_markets* as well.

Your context class should have at least these properties:

```
// Represents the Products table in the database.
public DbSet<Product> products { get; set;}

// Represents the Distributor table in the database.
public DbSet<Distributor> distributors { get; set;}

// Represents the CountryMarkets table in the database.
public DbSet<Country_Market> country_markets { get; set;}
```

The way your entity classes are currently made, Entity Framework has no way of determining the relationship between them.

Here's some information based on an example:
 If you want to have a one-to-one relationship between two classes, say *Product* and *Distributor*. One of the two classes will need to have a property referencing the other.
Lets say a *product* has a particular *distributor*, your code would look like this:

```
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public int product_id { get; set; }

    public Distributor distributor { get; set; }
}

public class Distributor
{

    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

That's how you define a one-to-one relationship between two entity classes.
Now, let's say a *product* can have many *distributors*. As you guessed it, a one-to-many relationship. Your code would then look like this:

```
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public int product_id { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Distributor> distributors { get; set; }
}

public class Distributor
{

    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

Note: If you are going to add a new Product with an existing Distributor in the database, you will need to get this Distributor from the database **first** and add it to the *Distributor* property of the *Product*. Otherwise Entity Framework will complain that you are trying to add duplicate keys.

It is not necessary to create a class with a plural name of the entity that you want to persist. Maybe you need them for XML serialization/deserialization but for Entity Framework this is not needed. I personally would first deserialize the XML data into DTO (Data Transfer Object) classes and convert these to entity classes next.

Without too much context of your application, your entity classes would need to look something like this (without XML attributes for simplicity):

```
namespace project.Models    
{
    public class Product
    {
        [Key]
        public int product_id { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Distributor> Distributors { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Country_Market> Country_Markets { get; set; }
    }

    public class Distributor
    {    
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public string name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Country_Market
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public string shortcode { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I would also advice to add a primary key to the *Country_Market* entity class.
Just like in the example above.

Lastly, I would delete the database and run your code again to verify whether tables are created correctly.

Hope this helps and gives you a better understanding how Entity Framework sets relationships between entities.

Comment: Thanks for your time @dankmemester, after some experimenting with your answer I believe I will implement some DTO's. I don't know enough to start editing the generated code whilst keeping it compatible with both XML serialization and EF6 (I keep loosing information after editing my class when de-serializing from XML). Thanks for explaining how to setup the relationships, I will use that knowledge on my DTO's.

Comment: @EddieTedCrocombe great. yes, I would separate deserialization of XML data and data persistence from each other. Don't do them all together. Makes it slightly easier to test if you separate them. Also, I would recommend studying more in depth how you can use Entity Framework to store your data. Check this link out: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee712907(v=vs.113).aspx and try the links to your left. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the class generated from xsd.exe by changing all of the arrays to Lists (Most discussions on this topic say to use ICollections, but whenever i scaffold, i get an error specifying that interfaces cannot be used).

I also removed the object array and replaced it with individual classes (in the XSD schema, these elements have a max of 1 occurrence, no need for List<>'s of them)

```
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
public class Product
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    [Key]
    public int product_id { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Country_Markets", typeof(Country_Markets), Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public Country_Markets { get; set; }
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Distributors", typeof(Distributors), Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public Distributors items { get; set; }
}
```

I then marked both the Distributors and Country_Markets classes as a *System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.ComplexType* by annotating them.

```
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[ComplexType]                       // <-- See addition here
public class Distributors
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Distributor", Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public List<Distributor> Distributor { get; set; }

    // navigation property used to define the many-to-many relationship
    public virtual List<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[ComplexType]                       // <-- and here
public class Country_Markets
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Country_Market", Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public List<Country_Market> Country_Market { get; set; }

    // navigation property used to define the many-to-many relationship
    public virtual List<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

By marking these classes as ComplexType, EF will look as these classes as a "Value Class", that contain no PrimaryKey or unique identifiers, and therefor merge it onto the table that is referencing it.

A total of 5 tables will still be created, Product, Distributor, Country_Markets and a further 2 for many-to-many relationship between Product >< Distributor && Product >< Country_Markets.